# REGEXP : find the first character after one specific other character

Tags: regex, ibm-doors

this is my problem :

I have a similar list of strings like that :

```
1) mytext-othertext-01-Onemore
2) mytext1-othertext1-02-Twomore
3) mytext2-othertext2-03-Fourmore
4) ...
```

I'm tryng to get **ONLY** the **FIRST** character after the third **"-"** in my text so the result would be :

```
1) O => because mytext-othertext-01-Onemore
2) T => because mytext1-othertext1-02-Twomore
3) F => because mytext2-othertext2-03-Fourmore
```

I'm pretty bad using regexp and i assume that is not probably a hard one but i'm stuck with this at the moment :

```
\-(.*)
```

[Example of result](https://regex101.com/r/2nTXAU/1)

**That will took the entire text after the first "-" as you can see**

Help will be hardly appreciated to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?:[^-]*-){3}(.)
```

`[^-]*-` matches a sequence (possibly empty) of non-hyphens followed by hyphen. `{3}` after that matches it 3 times, so it finds the 3rd hyphen, and `^` at the beginning makes it start matching from the beginning of the string. The capture group `(.)` captures the next character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nnDmWH/1)